# Why is my Bot responding with a MethodNotAllowed error?

Tags: facebook, azure, botframework, slack

I just started looking into the new Microsoft Bot Framework.

- https://dev.botframework.com

I started with this sample:

- http://docs.botframework.com/connector/getstarted/#getting-started-in-net

My new bot responds in the emulator (both local version and deployed in Azure), with the default template's sample response "You sent X characters".

Once connected to Slack and FB Messenger, I am getting responses from the Bot, but it's an error message that says "Operation returned an invalid status code 'MethodNotAllowed'"

Before I go any further and add more features, what can I do to troubleshoot and fix this, so that I can get the sample response to work via Slack and FB Messenger?

EDIT: in the dev portal, I don't get any response or error.

Thanks in advance! :-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Give it 30s to see if you get an internet timeout because it can't find your bot.  I'm guessing that maybe http vs https are out of whack on the endpoint or you're missing the /api/messages part of the endpoint URL that comes with the Bot Application template.

Comment: It responds pretty quickly on both Slack and FB messenger. The endpoint is there because I haven't edited the template. It works in the emulator using both a local URL and the Azure URL, responding with the sample message each time.

Comment: Update: I realized that I *was* missing the /api/messages/ at the end of the endpoint URL. And yes, I did need to use https instead of http. Thanks!!! :)